# How to convert an integer N to an array of Size N in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable number = 7

I want to convert it to an array size of 7,

I need like this arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

How Can I do that easily in JavaScript without using any loop ?

```js
number = 7
ara = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```